# Select only inline code blocks

Tags: regex

I need to select every inline code blocks (not multilane)

Here is text https://regex101.com/r/8e7nPL/7

Example of inline blocks that I need to extract: `f.call();`, `yield()`, `Fiber`

Answer (score 1):

this could help you:

```js
function test(text) {
  var re = /`([^`\n]+)`/g;

  let match;
  while(match = re.exec(text)) {
    console.log('match', match);
  }


}


test(
`
Пример создания файбера и передача ему в качестве аргумента вызываемой функции:
\`\`\`
auto f = new Fiber(&foo);
\`\`\`
\`f.call();\` вызов файбера
\`Fiber.yield();\` метод \`yield()\` класса \`Fiber\` вызывающий преостановку выполнение текущей функции

Пример:

\`\`\`
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main()
{
  auto f = new Fiber(&foo);
  f.call(); // Prints Hello
  f.call(); // Prints World
}

void foo()
{
  writeln("Hello");
  Fiber.yield();
  writeln("World");
}
\`\`\`

Результат:
\`\`\`
> app.exe
Hello
World\`
`
)
```